# how do i list all .bat files in a folder in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

How do i create an ArrayList in an ArrayList containing the folders in a folder and the programs inside those folders?

like this:

> ArrayList
>
> > folders inside the `plugins` folder
> >
> > > all batch files inside these folders

EDIT:

i want to list this:

`program/plugins/vlams/plugin1.bat`

`program/plugins/vlams/plugin2.bat`

as this:

`plugins by vlams`

`-plugin1`

`-plugin2`

Comment: There's  no such thing  as an *ArrayList* in a batch file, so there's no way to create an *ArrayList in an ArrayList* either. What you're attempting to do is going to be somewhat difficult in a batch file; is there some specific reason you're restricted to using one?

Comment: Im not really restricted to use a batch file but there is no other language on a clean windows PC that can be coded very easy and i dont know enough of python and java to make it out of that.

Comment: @KenWhite - It's not _super_ hard, you just end up making an arraylike and not an actual array. You'll have a group of variables called folder[1], folder[2], folder[3], etc. except they won't actually be related in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off
pushd C:\...\program\plugins\
:: Edit Above Path Path 
for /d %%a in (*) do (
  Echo Plugins by %%a 
  for /r "%%~a" %%b in (*.bat) do (
    Echo  - %%~nb
  )
  Echo.
)
popd
```

If the contents of Plugins is:

```
Plugins
> Vlams
  > plugin1.bat
  > plugin2.bat
> George
  > plugin1.bat
  > ReadMe.txt
```

The output will be:

```
Plugins by Vlams
 - plugin1
 - plugin2

Plugins by George
 - plugin1
```

Which I believe is what you want. Formatting the code should not be too much of a problem.

If you want to do something to these other than `Echo` them simply replace:

```
Echo  - %%~nb
```

with whatever you want, where `%%a` refers to the author(Folder name) and `%%b` refers to the name of the bat file.

Comment: Thanks, but one question, how do i make it so you type the name of someones plugin and then it launches it via _call_?

Comment: Maybe its possible to make a TMP folder wich contains all existing plugins and when your done it removes it again.

Comment: I found a little downside, i just searched the syntax for pushd and its not smart how this is used becouse this is going to be a program for people to use and i dont want people to have to change the directory everytime thers an update. You first need to open the folder that the batch file is in and then do pushd plugins